# Setting HTML frame src not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am tasked to rewrite Javascript code built from the year 2000 because it only works in an IE browser. It needs to work in all browsers.

Obviously this was well before AJAX and they used framesets (not even iframe yet) to execute remote JSP/servlet calls into an HTML frame. These frames don't display any HTML other than the main frame. Then you need to make sure you update the code references to know which code to execute from which frame. The frames are a headache, but I have gotten these calls to work in all browsers except Safari.

```
$('frame[name="RegtypeFrame"]', window.parent.document).attr("src", url);
```

From there, I am going to the top most document to find the specific frame to load. The url variable is a JSP page that has javascript created by Java scriptlets. Nightmare, yes, but I don't have time/approval to re-write from scratch.

I have tried window.top in Safari but no luck. The code does not execute at all in Safari. I have also tried bypassing the frames altogether by using an AJAX GET, which works in all browsers, but since it is javascript I have to use eval which is a valid security risk.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    async: true,
    dataType: "html"
}).done(
function(html)
{
    // major security risk to use eval on remote javascript code
    var dom = $(jQuery.trim(html));
    dom.filter('script').each(function()
    {
        $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
    });
}).fail(
function(jqXHR, textStatus)
{
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternatives on how to resolve this issue? I have a workaround but it is a flawed security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The original code seems to be working in Safari now, though I'm not sure of the reason why. I cleared the developer cache on previous attempts. Maybe there are other caches I'm not aware of. If you attempt to select the frame by id, it won't work for a non-iframe.

```
$('frame[name="RegtypeFrame"]', window.parent.document).attr("src", url);
```